# A column name keep coming with data when i append to list with peewee query

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have some problem when i want to append a data that i query by using peewee. I want to make a list which contain only numbers but a tables name is coming with my data. I need to remove them and i don't know how to do

```
_query = Orders.select(Orders.order_id).where(
                    (Orders.seller_id == _seller_id)
batch_size = 100
for _order_id in range(0,len(_query),batch_size):
    print(_query[_order_id:_order_id+batch_size])
```

result are

```
[<Orders: 1>, <Orders: 2>, <Orders: 3>, <Orders: 4>, <Orders: 5>, <Orders: 6>, <Orders: 7>]
```

the result i want is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should [learn about `map` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python. Something like that might help:

```
for _order_id in range(0,len(_query),batch_size):
  q = _query[_order_id:_order_id+batch_size]
  r = q.map( lambda x: x.id, q )
  print(list(p))
```

Now for each element of `q` you will get corresponding `id` value. I am not sure, how your model works, so you should adapt that.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = Orders.select(Orders.order_id).where(Orders.seller_id == _seller_id)
order_ids = [order_id for order_id, in query.tuples()]

for i in range(0, len(order_ids), 100):
    print(order_ids[i:i + 100])
```